# how can I edit and save my files from anywhere?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I use MS Word and Excel a lot. However, when i'm at work I send copy of my work to email and when i'm at home I download the copy from the email and so forth.

I need a way to make my copies update itself and I can find it from any machine worldwide. I need the way to be secure so no one can edit ot view my files.

Comment: There are many services that provide this capability. Requests for product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the CLOUD.

You can have very good solutions with Google ([drive](http://docs.google.com/)) and with Microsoft ([One drive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-en/))

Comment: Upvote for taking the effort of answering such a stupid question.

Comment: I just try to help and respond to each one according to their level.
Not everyone has the same knowledge of technology.